# How to capture page links with Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

my code is not capturing all group links

I participate in 120 groups but the code returns only 60

```
driver.get("")
driver.maximize_window()
sleep(5)

botao_entrar = driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "Entrar").click()
sleep(2)
campo_email = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='m_login_email']").send_keys(email)
sleep(2)
campo_senha = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='m_login_password']").send_keys(senha, Keys.ENTER)
sleep(50)
###################################################################################################

links = []

for i in range(8):
        print("Rolar Pagina")
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0, 400)")
        sleep(1)

#grupos = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='root']/table/tbody/tr/td/div[2]/ul/li/table/tbody/tr/td/a")
grupos = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "_7hkg")
for elm in grupos:
        link = elm.get_attribute("href")
        #link = elm.get_attribute("href").replace("m.","")
        print(link)
        links.append(link) 
        data = {'URL': links} 
        df = pd.DataFrame(data)
        df.to_excel(r"C:\__Imagens e Planilhas Python\Facebook\LinksGrupo.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')
        print(df)
```

I tried to use AbsXpath
CSSLECTOR

and I didn't get all the links on the page

Comment: Is it possible that you are not scrolling enough to load all of the groups you are in (or that you are not waiting enough between scrolls to load the additional content)?

Comment: I would use `grupos = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a._7hkg")`, and check that the scroll is enough (first see if 16 scrolls with 2sec waits in between changes the number of links you get)